# Why does Fsharp.Core use GetEnumerator instead of for

Tags: f#

I'v been looking at the implementation of F# Seq methods - https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs.

Here is the scan implementation as an example:

```
[<CompiledName("Scan")>]
let scan<'T,'State> f (z:'State) (source : seq<'T>) = 
    checkNonNull "source" source
    let f = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_,_,_>.Adapt(f)
    seq { let zref = ref z
          yield !zref
          use ie = source.GetEnumerator() 
          while ie.MoveNext() do
              zref := f.Invoke(!zref, ie.Current)
              yield !zref }
```

It gets the enumerator, and uses a while loop to iterate(it has to call MoveNext).

Couldn't it be changed to this?

```
[<CompiledName("Scan")>]
let scan<'T,'State> f (z:'State) (source : seq<'T>) = 
    checkNonNull "source" source
    let f = OptimizedClosures.FSharpFunc<_,_,_>.Adapt(f)
    seq { let zref = ref z
          yield !zref
          for i in source do
              zref := f.Invoke(!zref, i)
              yield !zref }
```

Which uses a for loop.

Is it just that someone with an odd coding style wrote that code and nobody has changed it?

Comment: These two versions of code do pretty much the same thing. The loop `for ... in ...` is the same as `foreach` loop in C#. It also gets enumerator and calls `.MoveNext()` implicitly

Comment: @Petr That's my point.  In this case, a for loop is definitely easier to read and cleaner, so why wouldn't you use the for loop.

Comment: I believe it's just matter of style. Maybe the author of code prefer more explicit style

Comment: @Petr It seems odd to me that the source code of the language doesn't make use of a feature of the language that was made for this exact scenario.

Comment: @phil: F# codebase makes all sorts of concessions in the name of performance. Perhaps that's one of the cases, even if it's hard to picture that.

Comment: It could also be that earlier versions of the LKG (Last known good) compiler didn't support `for` expressions over `IEnumerable` or didn't generate good IL-code together with `Seq` expressions. It's all speculations. If you think the code is substantially improved by using `for` over use/while I encourage you to submit a PR to the F# compiler project.